# Display view instead of text if @yield is empty

Tags: php, laravel

With blade, it is possible to show a default value if there is no data to @yield, like so:

```
@yield('section', 'Default Content');
```

But I would really like to show a view instead of a string text. The reason is that I want to `@yield` a navigation menu into a layout. Most of the times the navigation menu will be exactly the same, so a default option of some sort should be optimal here, but I would like a way to override the menu.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To check if the section exists you could use:

```
array_key_exists('fooSection', View::getSections())
```

and to check if the section is empty you could use:

```
empty(View::getSections()['fooSection'])
```

For example:

```
@section('fooSection')
Foo
@stop

@section('barSection')
Bar
@stop

<h1>If Section Exists</h1>
@if (array_key_exists('fooSection', View::getSections()))
@yield('fooSection')
@else
@yield('barSection')
@endif

<h1>If Section isn't Empty</h1>
@if (!empty(View::getSections()['fooSection']))
@yield('fooSection')
@else
@yield('barSection')
@endif
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In the meanwhile I found this: `@yield('navigation', View::make('layout.include.navigation'))` Though it is not possible to use something like `@yield('navigation', 'Controller@function')` which sucks bigtime for variables and such.